# Execute script on another server with file transfer

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, file-transfer

So I have a server running ubuntu 10.04 and I am using this program to merge PDFs called pdftk.

It has a bug when I run it on 10.04, but not when I installed it on 14.04 (or presumably 12.04). Unfortunately upgrading the server is not a possibility at this time. So I am trying to proceed with an alternate method.

I am running PHP scripts to generate the pdfs on the 10.04, and the files will be saved on that server, but I would like to use the functionality of the 14.04 to execute the merge of PDF files.

So I am just wondering wether this is this possible? Would the 14.04 version be able to access the publicly available PDFS, or would I have to copy over the files first, execute the merge, then return the merged file?

Any example scripts would be greatly appreciated.

To merge the files via php, I currently use this command (which doesn't work on 10.04)

```
exec('pdftk ' . $base_pdf_path . ' fill_form ' . $fdf_path . ' output ' . $filled_path);
```

Sincere thanks for the help.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 went to end-of-support status last April. You should not be using it anyway, so take this opportunity to upgrade to 14.04 and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I am aware... I have considered that but due to time constraints, not possible.